# What coordinate systems and bounds should i use integrating this? Moreover am i required to add two integrals?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y) = x^2y$, set up the integral of this function in the orders $dxdy$, $dydx$ as well as in polar coordinates over the following two regions:

i- $R_1$ : The region is in the ﬁrst quadrant and is below the line $y = 2$, to the left of the line $x = 3$, above the line $y = 0$ and outside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

ii- $R_2$ : The region is inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ but to the left of the line $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find the boundary of your domain is to draw a little bit. Just something like that is enough to see what we want :

[image]

Then, I think that the easiest way to integrate is to stay in cartesian coordinate. Indeed, in such domains where there are lines delimiting the boundaries, it's getting really hard to integrate using the polar coordinates.

To find the boundary of your circle, you can simply use the fact that :
$$
x^2+y^2=1 
$$ 
so you get y as a function of x
$$
y = ±\sqrt{1-x^2} 
$$
to define your boundary.

Hence, for the first domain, you should split your total integral into 2 integrals:

- The first one : x goes from 0 to 1, and y goes from   $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to 2.
- The second : x goes from 1 to 3, ans y goes from 0 to 2

You should do something similar for your second domain.

Comment: how do i change it to polar coordinates as well?

Comment: It's really more complicated to express a line in polar coordinates than to express a circle (or any cylinder) in cartesian coordinates. If you want to do so, you should first get expression of x = cst as a constraint between r and $\theta$ then do your integration. But really, it's really not convenient and you don't want to do that most of the time